# Resize the above picture as the below picture resizes

Tags: html, css

I made my website responsive that it will look good in all devices. I have this image that will scale down if it has to. However, the image above it which is its information doesn't. It's just the same size at all browser sizes. Also, when the browser decreases, the image above moves out of div container bears.

HTML:

```
<div id="bears">
   <img src="./pics/bearone.jpg">
   <div id="text">
     <img src="./pics/bearinfo.png">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bears img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display:block;
 }

#bears{
    margin-top: -40px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
  }

#text { float: right; margin-right: 750px; }
#text img { max-width: 50%; height: auto; margin-top: -55%; position: absolute;}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score -1):

Set the height and width of the image. and a css style rule for the image tag (or add a class for it).

```
<div id="bears">
   <img src="bearimage.jpg" width="200px" height="10px">
   <div id="text">
    <img src="bearimagetextimage.jpg" width="200px" height="10px">
   </div>
</div>
<style> img { height:auto;width:100%} </style>
```